# jquery to wrap divs in to columns

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a parent div, with 19 child divs with the same class like so:

```
<div id="dropdown-content1">
    <div class="CatsColumn"></div>
    <div class="CatsColumn"></div>
    <div class="CatsColumn"></div>
    <div class="CatsColumn"></div>
    <div class="CatsColumn"></div>
    <div class="CatsColumn"></div>
    <div class="CatsColumn"></div>
    <div class="CatsColumn"></div>
    <div class="CatsColumn"></div>
    <div class="CatsColumn"></div>
    <div class="CatsColumn"></div>
    <div class="CatsColumn"></div>
    <div class="CatsColumn"></div>
    <div class="CatsColumn"></div>
    <div class="CatsColumn"></div>
    <div class="CatsColumn"></div>
    <div class="CatsColumn"></div>
    <div class="CatsColumn"></div>
    <div class="CatsColumn"></div>
</div>
```

This is built dynamically so I need jQuery to wrap it into 3 columns with the same class name. I understand a little bit of jquery so I'm assuming .wrap() would be used, but my issue is that I don't how to tell the jquery to grab the first 7, then the next 7, and then the remaining 5 and wrap them in individual divs, so I have 3 columns. I appreciate any help!

Comment: Why not just use CSS? https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/bcgmorw8/

Comment: That's basic math. Do some research on modulo `%`.

Answer (score 2):

One way of achieving this using CSS would be to use `column-count`. See [CSS multi-column layouts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns/Using_multi-column_layouts).

```
#dropdown-content1 {
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  column-count: 3;
}
```

```css
#dropdown-content1 {
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  column-count: 3;
}
```

```html
<div id="dropdown-content1">
  <div class="CatsColumn">1</div>
  <div class="CatsColumn">2</div>
  <div class="CatsColumn">3</div>
  <div class="CatsColumn">4</div>
  <div class="CatsColumn">5</div>
  <div class="CatsColumn">6</div>
  <div class="CatsColumn">7</div>
  <div class="CatsColumn">8</div>
  <div class="CatsColumn">9</div>
  <div class="CatsColumn">10</div>
  <div class="CatsColumn">11</div>
  <div class="CatsColumn">12</div>
  <div class="CatsColumn">13</div>
  <div class="CatsColumn">14</div>
  <div class="CatsColumn">15</div>
  <div class="CatsColumn">16</div>
  <div class="CatsColumn">17</div>
  <div class="CatsColumn">18</div>
  <div class="CatsColumn">19</div>
</div>
```

---

If you really need to add wrappers to the columns, you can do something like this to generate a DOM like:

```
<div id="dropdown-content1">
    <div class="ColWrapper">
        <div class="CatsColumn"></div>
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="ColWrapper">
        <div class="CatsColumn"></div>
        ...
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

```js
let columns = 3;
let elements = 19;

let elementsPerCol = Math.ceil(elements / columns);

let $dropdownContent = $("#dropdown-content1");
var $colWrapper;

var currentCol = -1;
for (var i = 0; i < elements; i++) {
  if (currentCol < Math.floor(i / elementsPerCol)) {
    // Create a new wrapper whenever the existing 
    // column is completely filled with elements.
    $colWrapper = $('<div class="ColWrapper"></div>').appendTo($dropdownContent);
    currentCol++;
  }

  // Generate the column element, and append to the
  // current wrapper.
  $colWrapper.append('<div class="CatsColumn">' + i + '</div>');
}
```

```css
.ColWrapper {
  outline: 1px #AAA solid;
  width: 33%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dropdown-content1">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Little different approach, by using [slice()](https://api.jquery.com/slice/):

*(edited as i've seen that all guys added improvements, so i tried too:))*

```js
len=$('.CatsColumn').length;
cols=3; //number of desired columns
rows=Math.ceil(len/cols);


for(i=0;i<len;i+=rows) {

$('.CatsColumn').slice(i,i+rows).wrapAll("<div class='column'>");

}
```

```css
.column {
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px solid red;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dropdown-content1">
    <div class="CatsColumn">1</div>
    <div class="CatsColumn">2</div>
    <div class="CatsColumn">3</div>
    <div class="CatsColumn">4</div>
    <div class="CatsColumn">5</div>
    <div class="CatsColumn">6</div>
    <div class="CatsColumn">7</div>
    <div class="CatsColumn">8</div>
    <div class="CatsColumn">9</div>
    <div class="CatsColumn">10</div>
    <div class="CatsColumn">11</div>
    <div class="CatsColumn">12</div>
    <div class="CatsColumn">13</div>
    <div class="CatsColumn">14</div>
    <div class="CatsColumn">15</div>
    <div class="CatsColumn">16</div>
    <div class="CatsColumn">17</div>
    <div class="CatsColumn">18</div>
    <div class="CatsColumn">19</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `i%7` would not work if there are more than 21 `.CatsColumn`s. It would create a 4th column instead.

Comment: @JohnBupit, right, but not sure if requirement is: 3 columns in any case, or 3 columns in this specific case? :)

Comment: Also, the for loop can be optimised to `for(var i = 0; i < len; i += 7)` and the if condition can be removed.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a jQuery plugin to do the job!

I just added a function to specify how many columns you wanted and what the class name will be.

```js
/* Create a jQuery Plugin */
(function($) {
  $.fn.columnize = function(config) {
    var defaults = {
      colCount       : 3,
      wrapperElement : $('<div class="wrapper-element">'),
      transpose      : false
    };
    config = $.extend(defaults, config || {}); // Apply defaults 
    var perColumn    = Math.ceil(this.children().size() / config.colCount);
    var colWidth     = (100 / config.colCount).toFixed(3) + '%';
    var $columns     = [];
    for (var col = 0; col < config.colCount; col++) {
      $columns.push(config.wrapperElement.clone().css({
        display : 'inline-block',
        width   : colWidth
      }));
    }
    this.children().each(function(index, child) {
      $(child).appendTo($columns[
        config.transpose !== false
          ? (index % config.colCount)     // Items added Left to Right
          : Math.floor(index / perColumn) // Items added Top to Bottom
      ]);
    });
    return this.empty().append($columns);
  };
})(jQuery);

$(function() {
  // Columnize the existing list! Default is already set to 3.
  $('#dropdown-content1').columnize({
    wrapperElement : $('<div>').addClass('ColWrapper') // Override default wrapper.
  });
});
```

```css
.ColWrapper {
  outline: 1px #DDD solid;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dropdown-content1">
  <div class="CatsColumn">1</div>
  <div class="CatsColumn">2</div>
  <div class="CatsColumn">3</div>
  <div class="CatsColumn">4</div>
  <div class="CatsColumn">5</div>
  <div class="CatsColumn">6</div>
  <div class="CatsColumn">7</div>
  <div class="CatsColumn">8</div>
  <div class="CatsColumn">9</div>
  <div class="CatsColumn">10</div>
  <div class="CatsColumn">11</div>
  <div class="CatsColumn">12</div>
  <div class="CatsColumn">13</div>
  <div class="CatsColumn">14</div>
  <div class="CatsColumn">15</div>
  <div class="CatsColumn">16</div>
  <div class="CatsColumn">17</div>
  <div class="CatsColumn">18</div>
  <div class="CatsColumn">19</div>
</div>
```

You can use `$.fn.wrapAll` too, if you want to simplify this. This alleviates the use of buidling an array.

```
var childSelector = '.CatsColumn';

for (var col = 0; col < config.colCount; col++) {
  var startIndex = (col * (perColumn - 1)) + col;
  var endIndex   = startIndex + perColumn;

  $(childSelector).slice(startIndex, endIndex).wrapAll(config.wrapperElement.clone().css({
    display : 'inline-block',
    width   : colWidth
  }));
}
```

Comment: The 19th div seems to be missing. Using `Math.ceil` to calculate `perColumn` should fix this.

Comment: As an improvement to the plugin, would it make more sense to pass a `colWrapperElement` to the plugin, instead of passing `colClassName`. The wrapper element can then be cloned and wrapped around the column divs. Something like this perhaps: `$('#dropdown-content1').columnize({ wrapperElement : $('<tagname ...></tagname>') });`

Comment: @JohnBupit I utilized a wrapper config. I tried using `$.wrap()` and `$.wrapAll()` in my earlier trials, but the math was too complex and it did not work so well on column sizes greater than 5. I even added the ability to transpose the column data. :)